# The torch_geometric.data.Data constructor output does not keep the x value

Tags: machine-learning, graph, pytorch-geometric

I'm trying to create an data structure from a given adjacency matrix and a nodes features tensor.
I used networkx to organize the edge_index/attr. But the final Data object does not keep the x neither the y.

The code a wrote is:

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data

(...)
        g = from_networkx(nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjacency_matrix))

        g = Data(
            x=nodes,
            y=label,
            edge_index=g.edge_index,
            edge_attr=g.weight.unsqueeze(-1),
            partition=partition,
        )

        return g
```

The final g obtained is `Data(edge_index=[2, 702], edge_attr=[702, 1], partition=1)`.
The nodes and label variables has the following attributes:

```
In[4]: nodes.shape
Out[4]: torch.Size([78, 128])
In[5]: nodes.dtype
Out[5]: torch.float32
In[6]: nodes.device
Out[6]: device(type='cpu')
In[7]: label.shape
Out[7]: torch.Size([1])
In[8]: label.dtype
Out[8]: torch.int64
In[9]: label.device
Out[9]: device(type='cpu')
(...)
In[13]: type(g.x)
Out[13]: NoneType
In[14]: nodes
Out[14]: 
tensor([[-1.7406e-01, -8.2816e-01, -8.8429e-01,  ..., -1.7493e-01,
         -1.7825e-01, -1.6337e-01],
        [-3.9090e-03, -7.3728e-03, -8.9997e-03,  ...,  1.0641e-03,
         -3.7037e-03, -3.5345e-03],
        [-3.9192e-03, -9.7629e-03, -1.2001e-02,  ..., -2.3178e-03,
         -1.6078e-03, -5.9511e-03],
        ...,
        [-2.0496e-03, -8.0081e-03, -7.7297e-03,  ..., -1.1776e-03,
         -1.0516e-03, -1.1635e-03],
        [-2.7285e-03, -7.7395e-03, -5.8228e-03,  ...,  1.2457e-03,
          6.4051e-04, -1.8431e-03],
        [-3.3346e-03, -5.8863e-03, -6.6071e-03,  ...,  1.8363e-03,
         -1.9301e-04, -6.3760e-04]])
In[8]: torch.__version__
Out[8]: '1.13.1'
In[10]: torch_geometric.__version__
Out[10]: '2.2.0'
In[11]: torch.cuda_version
Out[11]: '11.6'
```

I  have already tried to use different manners to pass the variables to the constructor. And using the pycharm debugger inside the constructor tried to make self.x = x but the x does not keep the desired value.